# Delete top row from MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL database running for some testing, that is getting its values for the table 'results' from a webpage. It contains some rows and columns.

When I try:

```
select * from results limit 10;
```

It is showing the first 10 lines from the database of some table.

Basically, I want to delete those rows. When I try:

```
delete from results where (select * from results limit 10) ;
```

It will not delete these rows and it ask this:

```
delete from results where (select * from results limit 10) ;
```

Also tried to do:

```
mysql> delete * from results where (select * from results limit 10) ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 from results where (select * from results l
imit 10)' at line 1
```

How can I delete these rows? Also how can I select the last 10 rows and delete them?

Comment: you tried to use orderby and limit to delete last 10 rows

Comment: query should be something like this: `select * from results orderBy ="any field" desc limit 10; `

Answer (score 2):

When using `limit`, you should always have an `order by`.  Fortunately, `delete` accepts `limit`, so:

```
delete r
    from results r
    order by id
    limit 10;
```

SQL tables have no concept of "first" rows, because they represent *unordered* sets.  Hence, if you want things in a particular order, you should use an `ORDER BY` clause.

Note:  You *can* use `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY`, but I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

You must do it like this way, depend of ORDER you'll delete first or last 10 rows:

```
DELETE FROM results ORDER BY id_filed DESC|ASC limit 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this:

```
DELETE FROM `results` ORDER BY `row` DESC LIMIT 0,10;
```

Hope this will help you (: